# How Do I make Date a Variable?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, if-statement, terminal

Right now i am trying to build a script that when run will get the date and store it as a variable so down the line it can be compared with another date value to see if they match 
My question is how do I do that and in what forms can you call the date command. This is a script in bash fyi, this is what I am currently trying to do

```
#Specific Set Variables 
SpecficDate=timestamp() {
  date +"%T %D"
}
SpecficStatus="Pass" #SetVariable 

echo $SpecficStatus
echo $SpecficDate
```

Any help would be great, thank you

Comment: not very sure what you mean. Could you elaborate what is your ultimate goal and give some examples?

Comment: @fedorqui Yeah sure, I am checking out two values from a repo date and status I then want to be able to compare those values and see if they match the dates would have to match each other and status would have to match each other. thats why I am trying to store date as a variable so I can call on it when I need to compare, since this will be called every couple of days

Comment: Create function as: `timestamp() {  date +"%T %D"; }` then store this value by calling function as: `SpecficDate=$(timestamp)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code something like this is what you could use

```
SpecficStatus="Pass" #SetVariable 
timestamp() { date +"%T %D"; }
SpecficDate=$(timestamp)

echo $SpecficStatus
echo $SpecficDate
```